# how to access the list inside a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a dictionary which is

```
a = {'subnets': [{'subnet': None}]}
```

I want to access the subnet value and set `subnet="something"`
How can I do it?

Comment: what have you tried? information like this is readily available in the docs. if you know how to get an item from a dictionary and index a list then you should be all set

Comment: You can do it like: a['subnets'][0]['subnet']="something"

Answer (score 1):

```
a={'subnets': [{'subnet': None}]}

b = a['subnets'] # now b = [{'subnet': None}]

c = b[0] # c = {'subnet': None}

d = c['subnet']

# in one line

info = a['subnets'][0]['subnet']

# setting the value to 'something'

a['subnets'][0]['subnet'] = 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value like:

```
someVariable = a['subnets'][0]['subnet']
```

You can set the value like:

```
a['subnets'][0]['subnet']="something"
```